# How to print text in columns (delimiter = space, ignore specific column with spaces inside)?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I would like to print an output text in 4 columns:

```
SharedCacheMap 0xb89e9720   None   \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\WWanAPI.dll
ImageSectionObject 0xb89ea5f8   None   \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention\Resource\0409\McTrayHipRL.dll    
DataSectionObject 0xb89ea5f8   None   \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention\Resource\0409\McTrayHipRL.dll
```

I tried:

```
column -s " " -t
```

I don't know how to handle the spaces in the file pathes.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while read -r c1 c2 c3 rest; do printf "%-20s %-12s %-8s %s\n" "$c1" "$c2" "$c3" "$rest"; done < file
```

Output:

```
SharedCacheMap       0xb89e9720   None     \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\WWanAPI.dll
ImageSectionObject   0xb89ea5f8   None     \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention\Resource\0409\McTrayHipRL.dll
DataSectionObject    0xb89ea5f8   None     \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention\Resource\0409\McTrayHipRL.dll
```

Comment: Hm, but all backslashes in the filepath are gone.

Comment: I've updated my answer and added option `-r` to read command.

Answer (score 0):

with sed removing spaces only in filenames strings

```
cat yourfile.txt | sed 's/[^\]*\\/&\$\n/' | sed '2~2 s/ //g' | sed ':a; N; $! ba; s/\$\n//g'
```

or replace them with %20

```
cat yourfile.txt | sed 's/[^\]*\\/&\$\n/' | sed '2~2 s/ /%20/g' | sed ':a; N; $! ba; s/\$\n//g'
```